# IE 6 png transparency issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

My page is not rendering properly in ie6 because of transparency problem in ie 6. How can fix this issue.

Comment: Also, you should not think about IE until IE16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use the IE PNG Fix from [TwinHelix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/). Works well with alpha-transparent pngs in IE6. You just need to include a tiny file into your html-code. The site explains well how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't support transparent PNGs at all.

You need to use the Alpha Image Renderer. Check out the JS script fix found here:

[PNG in Windows IE](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/bobosola/index.htm)

There's also a fix from TwinHelix:

[IE PNG Fix -TwinHelix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/)

Comment: wrong ie6 supports png8 http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/03/20/making-ie6-friendly-png8-images/

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Answer (score 1):

[SuperSleight](http://24ways.org/2007/supersleight-transparent-png-in-ie6)

Answer (score 0):

[PNG Fix](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/)

image and background-image fixed